# Looking for a win32 log file reader

Tags: log-files

I'm looking for a win32 app that can be auto refreshed, with some advanced find features, but more important, that's able to read a text file backward (i.e. last line on top).

Do you know any app that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) fulfills the specific requirements you ask for. Your request for "advanced find features" is too vague for me to answer. Do you mean regex searching?

Comment: yep, RegEx is fine. I used BareTail, but it trails the log as it's produced, it doesn't display it backward. Did I miss an option?

Answer (score 1):

[SnakeTail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/) is a Windows tail program that can monitor and search log files.

[Log Expert](http://www.log-expert.de/) is another good alternative.

Here is a good list of other  [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/tag/tail/)

Answer (score 1):

I really like Hoo WinTail... You can set up filters and highlighting and even have it watch a log file and email you if it spots specific text.

http://www.hootech.com/WinTail/

Answer (score 0):

Uh, not so so advanced, but PowerShell has rudimentary tail functionality within `get-content \path\to\file.log -wait`.  I am not sure what you can do with the output afterwards to invert it the way you want.  I would be mad impressed if someone shows me up and gives you workable code.  I will probably get marked down, because my answer is somewhat "well, build your own."  There is also Tail for Win32, but I am not sure it has the functionality you are looking for; I only used its basic features when I needed it.

While looking at Tail for Win32 and the functionality you wanted (specifically last line first), I stumbled upon [this Google project](http://sites.google.com/site/taillive/mainscreen).  Let me know if that tickles your fancy.  I would be curious about your results.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the binary downloaded wouldn't load, moaning about an unregistered ocx. As I vowed not to do any VB6 anymore (I mean, a log file reader written in VB6?), I stopped this experiment.